# Ask for user permissions in LinkedIn application

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

With PHP api for LinkedIn , how to ask for user permissions at the time of application authorization ?

These are the permissions i need

- Your Profile Overview
- Your Full Profile
- Your Email Address

I tried but couldnt find anything , Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the last part of the doc http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your authentication string: `scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+r_fullprofile`

I will look as follows:

`https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+r_fullprofile`

More details: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting